# Suspected Duplicate Account - what should I do?

Tags: support, duplicate-accounts

I just found two very similar accounts and I think they propably belong to the same user.

Take a look on this question: [ANTLR4: Error message with complete offending source code line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019988/antlr4-error-message-with-complete-offending-source-code-line).

The user posts an answer (which is not really an answer but an addition to original question), from a different account than the he user to post the question.

And here is the accounts

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126956/marcel-schaible
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/5834410/marcel-schaible

Comment: Flag one of the users posts and explain it.  No need to call him out on meta.  It might be an innocent mistake.  He didn't even upvote his own post, so I double it is really an effort to use a sock puppet account to gain rep.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I also think that this is not sock puppet case, I just do not know how exactly to handle it. Thats why I am posting it here. I will follow you suggestion and flag one of the posts

Comment: I think low-rep users get a warning when they post an answer to their own question.  Reminding them it is not a forum or somesuch.  He worked around it the way a programmer would and created a new account :)

Comment: Yeah - if this was sock-puppetry, it would be the worst attempt ever:)

Comment: @HansPassant I was not aware of that. Maybe this is the case. However, the 'things' tha he posted can not considered as an answer (but this is another issue)

Comment: LOL. It's definitely the same users - look at the avatars ;)